# Xamarin forms Bind to ColumnDefinition Width Property

Tags: xamarin, grid, xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind the widthproperty of a column definition, but can't seem to get the binding to take. Can anyone tell me how to bind to a Xamarin Grid column definition to a property?

Binding property in custom class:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty PointsColumnsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PointsBarColumns), typeof(ColumnDefinitionCollection), typeof(RewardsPanel), new ColumnDefinitionCollection());
```

This is my property:

```
public GridLength PointsFill {
    get => (GridLength)GetValue(PointsFillProperty);
    set => SetValue(PointsFillProperty, value);
}
```

This is how I am setting the binding:

```
_pointsBar.ColumnDefinitions[0].SetBinding(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, nameof(PointsFill));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the binding context on the _pointsBar.

```
        _pointsBar = new Grid
        {
            BackgroundColor   = BasicStyle.PrimaryColor,
            Style             = BasicStyle.PointsAndVisits, BindingContext = this,
            ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Star) }
            }
        };
```